# Curl not working, error: couldn't connect to host

Tags: php, curl

I am using curl to get weather information from a specific site api.wunderground.com and the issue is its not working.  I have tried using the file_get_contents function also, but its not working either.  Here is my code for curl:

```
function get_web_page($url)
        {
            //echo "curl:url<pre>".$url."</pre><BR>";
        $options = array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
            CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
            CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i
            CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 15,      // timeout on connect
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 15,      // timeout on response
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
            CURLOPT_PROXY          => null,

        );                  

        $ch         = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
        $content    = curl_exec( $ch );
        $err        = curl_errno( $ch );
        $errmsg     = curl_error( $ch );
        $header     = curl_getinfo( $ch,CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL );
        curl_close( $ch );

        $header['errno']   = $err;
        $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;

        //change errmsg here to errno
        if ($errmsg)
        {
            echo "CURL:".$errmsg."<BR>";
        }
        return $content;
        }

        $url        =   "http://api.wunderground.com/api/67927f145c532a19/geolookup/conditions/q/uae/dubai.json";

        get_web_page($url);
```

I have checked my server settings, curl is enabled and the server is using port 80.  Can anybody help me with this I am out of ideas.

Comment: What's the error, What's `not working`?

Comment: CURL:couldn't connect to host its showing this message i have search through all the options and what caught my eye is that my hosting is using port 80 thats why its not working

Comment: @user1309524: did you check my updated answer?

Comment: yeah i check its but still not working

Comment: I have same issue. Curl is enabled but error is couldn't connect to host. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 3):

you just need to echo the output.

```
echo get_web_page($url);
```

EDIT:

You may also use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
<?php
$url="http://api.wunderground.com/api/67927f145c532a19/geolookup/conditions/q/uae/dubai.json";
echo file_get_contents($url);
?>
```

Code update:

```
<?php
function get_web_page($url)
{    
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $curl_result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    return $curl_result;
}

$url="http://api.wunderground.com/api/67927f145c532a19/geolookup/conditions/q/uae/dubai.json";
echo get_web_page($url);
?>
```

Comment: its says CURL:couldn't connect to host

Comment: what will be the necessary settings for curl on your hosting

Comment: nothing special.. just curl is enabled.. by the way, you can try file_get_contents as it is also working fine. I can send you my phpinfo if you really want to go with cURL.

Comment: thats would be great bcz i already tried file_get_contents and its not working this is my info of hosting http://uaebby.org.ae/uaebby/info.php

Comment: please let me know the errors which you are getting.. Are you getting response by running the URL [http://api.wunderground.com/api/67927f145c532a19/geolookup/conditions/q/uae/dubai.json] in your browser?

Comment: yeah i m getting the response if i run the url directly but its not working i have used your code [link](http://uaebby.org.ae/uaebby/testing_code/index.php) but still no result

Comment: @Sandy did you check my hosting information their might be some issuse with it

Answer (score 0):

i tried the same code and got response as

{
    "response": {
        "version": "0.1"
        ,"termsofService": "http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html"
        ,"features": {
        "geolookup": 1
        ,
        "conditions": 1
        }

The above code is right. you simple forget to print the value returned by function

Comment: i tried it but its not working its still showing message CURL:couldn't connect to host

Comment: i am getting response very well. Did you check your phpinfo , maybe curls are not enabled

Comment: you can also use  file_get_contents($url) Both are returning same response

Comment: i have check the whole thing this is my phpinfo information  http://uaebby.org.ae/uaebby/info.php and let me know any idea thanks

Answer (score 0):

The API seems to block suspicious User Agents. Try using a standard browser User Agent instead of `spider`.

With normal ( a browser's user agent ) , the API returns normal response .

Comment: this is the link of my page [link](http://uaebby.org.ae/uaebby/testing_code/index.php) you can see the error

Comment: did you change your User Agent ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you connect to internet by proxy.you can get it by setting a proxy in curl_setopt function.its function well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add

```
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_PROXY => false,
```

it resolved the issue